# Running an ANT script from SCONS

Tags: java, android, ant, scons

Is it possible to run a particular ant script from scons?

For example running this script from the command line works

```
/usr/local/bin/ant release -f /Users/dev/pic/src/platform/android/java/build.xml
```

is it possible to have this successfully run in scons? I try this:

```
env.Command('local.properties', [], "/usr/local/bin/ant release -f /Users/dev/pic/src/platform/android/java/build.xml")
```

but that fails because it doesn't output the local.properties file with the correct SDK location

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/dev/pic/src/platform/android/java/build.xml:55: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

But those variables are correct. Is there a way to overcome this obstacle using scons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how and when you want to execute `ant`, but yes it is indeed possible.

If you want to execute this `ant` script every time `SCons` executes, then you can use the [SCons Execute()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp14528120) function, as follows:

```
env.Execute("/usr/local/bin/ant release -f /Users/dev/pic/src/platform/android/java/build.xml")
```

This will execute every time, with no target/source dependency checking.

If you only want this ant script to execute if a certain target is out of date, then use the [SCons Command()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands) function as follows:

```
env.Command(target='local.properties',
       source='/Users/dev/pic/src/platform/android/java/build.xml',
       action='/usr/local/bin/ant release -f $SOURCE')
```

Im not sure if I got the source and target files correct, you may need to fix it.

Notice that `SCons` only works with ***sources*** and ***targets*** that are in or below the `SCons` project directory hierarchy. The root of said hierarchy is where the `SConstruct` script is located.

Comment: Brady this was exactly what I needed to get the project to build correctly and you answered that question.